# Android Studio always starts with Java and won't let me start with Kotlin. How do I fix this?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, new-project

I just installed Android Studio and when I start a new project it starts with Java even though I've selected Kotlin. Please help.

I'm using the file - new - new project

Answer (score 1):

- After file - new - new project  select Empty Activity if you want to make a activity.

[image]

- After Empty Activity just select language Kotlin and click the finish button it will redirect your screen with kotlin project.

[image]

It will work because in my system that's work perfetly.